# Getting the Cumulative Distribution Function of f(x) from a dataset of x

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I've a data set $\mathcal{X}$ which consists of randomly generated numbers.

Let's say for example

```
data = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], 10^4];
```

My aim is to use Mathematica to obtain and plot the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $f(x)$, specifically the square root of $x\in \mathcal{X}$,  without generating a new  data set for $\sqrt{x}$.

Can somebody let me know how to take the approach here ?

Comment: Hi ! I don't think this is a *Mathematica* related issue rather than a mathematics one.

Comment: Hi @peeppeep, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Now that I did your homework, please take some time learn from the site and help others when you can. [Your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but its a good idea to wait a few hour for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you.

Answer (score 11):

First I create a set of data to simulate yours.

```
data = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], 10^4];
```

Now you can take advantage of the [`EmpiricalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) function to define a model-free distribution based on your data.

```
edist = EmpiricalDistribution[data];
```

The core of what you are asking for is to obtain a [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html), i.e starting from the distribution of $x$ to obtain the distribution of $f(x)$

```
ted = TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[x], x \[Distributed] edist];
```

Once you have any distribution, plotting the cumulative probability function becomes trivial using [`CDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF.html)

```
Plot[CDF[ted, x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that an empirical distribution that allows the possibility of negative numbers should be truncated  using  [`TruncatedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TruncatedDistribution.html) to avoid `Sqrt` of a negative.

```
ted = TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[x], x \[Distributed] TruncatedDistribution[{0,\[Infinity]},edist]];
```

Comment: Using a Normal distribution (which generates negative values) to illustrate does not seem ideal if the intention is to take square roots of the data.

Comment: @wolfies, I have changed the example to an `ExponentialDistribution`but kept the `TruncatedDistribution` explanation, as empirical distributions based on Kernel density may have non zero probability densities for `x<0`. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks for making this question useful!

Answer (score 3):

You can apply your transformation to your sample `data` and use `EmpiricalDistribution` on the transformed data without having to use `TransformedDistribution`:

```
data = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], 10^4];
ed = EmpiricalDistribution[data];
edtr = EmpiricalDistribution[Sqrt@data];

Plot[{CDF[ed, x], CDF[edtr, x]}, {x, 0, 4},
 PlotLegends -> {"CDF\nEmpiricalDistribution[data]", "CDF\nEmpiricalDistribution[Sqrt@data]"}]
```

[image]

```
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10^4];
ed2 = EmpiricalDistribution[data2];
edtr2 = EmpiricalDistribution[Abs@data2];

Plot[{CDF[ed2, x], CDF[edtr2, x]}, {x, -4, 4},
 PlotLegends -> {"CDF\nEmpiricalDistribution[data]",  "CDF\nEmpiricalDistribution[Abs@data]"}]
```

[image]